# Sidekiq Workers on Cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sidekiq

I have read through the available documentation about [background tasks on Cloud Foundry](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20378173-support-for-background-tasks-resque-delayed-job-cron) . But this hasn't helped on how one should deploy sidekiq to cloudfoundry?

How do I run,  `bundle exec sidekiq` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you push the application, instead of selecting 'Rails' for the framework, select 'other' and then 'standalone', you will then be prompted for a command to start the application with, this is where you would enter `bundle exec sidekiq`

Comment: The entire application is a Rails app and Sikdekiq is just a part of it. So, the way you are saying - how would the rails app be pushed? or they need to be pushed independently?

Comment: Independantly, yes, the easiest way is to maintain two manifests that you could swap depending on whether you wanted to push the worker or the web app. Or, you could write a script, like this... https://github.com/danhigham/log_squirrel/blob/master/deploy.rb, the former is probably easier though :-)

Comment: I did you said, but the tasks still don't run. In the logs, I just see that sidekiq started but no job was executed

Comment: Are you sure that a) that the sidekiq worker app is bound to the same redis instance and that b) the jobs are being created?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new manifest (`manifest.worker.yml`) and include the following:

```
applications:
  .:
    name: APPNAME-worker
    framework:
      name: standalone
      info:
        mem: 64M
        description: Standalone Application
        exec: 
    url: 
    path: .
    runtime: ruby19
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -e production
    mem: 256M
    instances: 1
    services:
      APPNAME-postgresql:
        type: postgresql
      APPNAME-redis:
        type: redis
```

Now to start your sidekiq worker:

```
vmc push --manifest manifest.worker.yml --path .
```

The services should be the same services you include in your web app's manifest.yml